# When answering this using the excel.csv and Pandas? I wrote out some code but it gives errors

Tags: python, pandas

I have to answer these questions. Based on [This data](https://brucepucci.github.io/final_data/ramen.csv)

Which country has the most elite level ramen bowls?

Which large brand produces the least consistent scores?

Assume review # is time based (Lower # means earlier)… Has the average starts changed over time?

Is the amount of detail in variety indicative of quality?

What “Style” of ramen would you prefer?

These are the questions I am answering.

my code is on the Juptyr Notes Google colab platform.

---

```
import os
import json

from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file path')

## Question 1.
frame1 = df[df.Style == 'Bowl']
frame1 = frame1.groupby('Country')['Stars'].mean

##now I get an error. I have seen it with a max instead of a mean and working but mean should work still.
```

Could someone help me through this?

---

Comment: "now I get an error. " **What error??**

Comment: Please see [ask], [help/on-topic], [mcve].

Comment: Ok fixed that Issue. Working on the rest and will be back thank you all for looking and helping :)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you check your data, in Stars columns there are some string entries named "Unrated". If you want, it is a good practice to delete this rows by filtering to keep only numeric data using a regular expression.

```
df = df[df.Stars.str.contains(r"\d")]
```

After that, transform Stars column to float type:

```
df["Stars"] = df["Stars"].apply(lambda x: float(x))
```

And now you can calculate whatever aggregated value:

```
frame1 = df[df.Style == 'Bowl']
frame1 = frame1.groupby('Country')['Stars'].mean()
```

```
Output:

Country
Canada         2.281250
China          3.527778
Hong Kong      3.735000
Japan          4.140278
Malaysia       4.281250
Philippines    3.375000
Singapore      4.096154
South Korea    3.865809
Taiwan         3.263514
Thailand       3.142045
UK             3.250000
USA            3.400000
Vietnam        3.362500
Name: Stars, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ok typed that in and got this /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:21: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: Ok so I tried again and got the first question thank you. I will work on the rest and be back :)